# Can I serve my bare git repository?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, server

I have a bare git repository on my Linux server.  In essence this is git server.

This server is also my web server.  A bare git repository is used as a central point of access for multiple developers.

But I would also like this bare repo to serve my web files.

I'm not sure if this is possible because the bare repo appears to not have a "normal" file structure.  All the files are in the objects folder.

I was following [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).

This is what the folder hierarchy of a bare repo looks like

[image]

In short, can my git server also be my web server?

Comment: A Git server does not necessarily have to be a bare repo. If you need the working-tree, make a regular repo.

Comment: That's how the docs describe it, they don't describe the "why" however.  What is a bare repo for then?  There has to be a reason they describe it this way.

Comment: A bare repo is a repo without working-tree. Nothing more, nothing less. If you don’t need working-tree (typical Git server), make a bare repo. If you need a working-tree (your Git+HTTP server), make a regular repo.

Comment: Right, but I just found another doc that states to use a bare repo for a server.  I think one of the reasons, is that you can not edit the files directly in a bare repo.  I think it is best practice to adhere to a client-server model of development instead of client to client.

Comment: It is not a good idea to push to a non-bare repo as it is ugly and a lot of hassle to keep everything clean and in sync. There is a hack to do it, but if you are new to git don't do it. If you are not new to git... still don't ;)

Comment: Exactly, there is a common "git pattern" I found here that talks about pushing to a bare repo and using hook to ... here it is ... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks

Comment: then I used what is called a post-receive hook!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a "bare" repository is that there is no "working directory". It only contains the information used by git.
If you have a "normal" repo, those files are in the .git directory in you repository.

So the answer is simply no.

But you can just clone the repository locally, then you have your files.

Comment: Is there a way to create a git repo that mimics the care repository so that whenever I push to the bare repo, the full repo "automatically" updates?

Comment: You can try to use the post-update hook to update a second local repository which contains the files. This can be accessible via http. If it is, take care to exclude the .git subdirectory so no one can access it via http. [Further reading on git hooks](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html)

Comment: sounds awesome ... from there when I push to the "git server" ( a bare repo ) a post-update hook will update an actual repository automatically.

Comment: post receive would be a better hook to use no?

Comment: In this case it should not matter, because you don't need the refs, I think. But maybe I don't remember correctly. post-update should work. I used it to set permissions some time ago.

Comment: I'm following this guide - only 1 year old - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks